# Perl: Creating ZIP archive whilst ignoring pathnames

Tags: perl, zip

Is it possible to create a ZIP archive using IO::Compress::Zip without retaining the full paths of the incoming files?

For example - if I add /tmp/foo/file.pdf to a zip file, I want the /tmp/foo path dropped when it is added to the archive. Is this possible? Is there another module that can do this?

Comment: I've usually done this by assembling the files I need in a single directory before I zip, but I know that's a cheap and space-inefficient short cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `FilterName` option in the [documentation for IO::Compress::Zip](http://www.metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aZip)

> Although this option can be used with the OO ointerface, it is of most
>   use with the one-shot interface. For example, the code below shows how
>   FilterName can be used to remove the path component from a series of
>   filenames before they are stored in $zipfile.
>
> ```
> sub compressTxtFiles
> {
>     my $zipfile = shift ;
>     my $dir     = shift ;
>
>     zip [ <$dir/*.txt> ] => $zipfile,
>         FilterName => sub { s[^$dir/][] } ;  
> }
> ```